# Font not change when change language locale android

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, locale

I have to change font as well while user select arabic language. But its not change font resources are changed.

If i restart app then it will change font as well. but restart activity on language change not working.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code where you change the font?

Comment: @javdromero i am changing locale so it should get font as per locale

Comment: I had this problem too! Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem. Actually its should change with locale but font directory with locale not working.

so i had just created value directory for other language where i had copy my style.xml for particular locale and copy font file in regular font directory instead of locale directory.

then in style file i just changed all text and component style with new font.